# View youtube videos in 720p by default in Safari?

Tags: safari, automator, script

Is there a way I can force safari to start youtube videos at 720p by default ?? I was wondering if there is an automator code that can achieve this ? Or maybe an extension that solely does that ? (I have found an extension that controls your youtube or whatever but I prefer something that only has one feature).

Although I have the settings already activated as the first answer suggested, I still have that problem.

Comment: You can use an alternative YouTube frontend: https://yewtu.be or other: https://redirect.invidious.io

Comment: @niutech  "Asked 11 years, 3 months ago"

Comment: So what? People still visit this page from Google Search in 2024.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an option in your Youtube settings to default to HD resolutions if they're available. It should be under Playback Settings>Video Playback Quality.

Comment: I do have that option turned on, but it maxes out at 420p...I have to manually change it to 720p !

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this Safari extension:

**Auto HD + FPS for YouTub‪e**

https://apps.apple.com/at/app/auto-hd-fps-for-youtube/id1546729687?mt=12